# Why does Jules laugh in the “Pulp Fiction” bar scene?

Tags: dialogue, pulp-fiction

In *Pulp Fiction* (1994), Jules starts laughing at Vincent’s answer when asked if he met Mia.

Why does he start laughing?

I never really understood the joke or what made it so funny.

Comment: Hi jacob, you may want to take the [tour].

Comment: Not sure why you are getting down votes, I wondered about this for a long time too.

Comment: When you watch the rest of the movie you understand why he was laughing. It's one of these "ah, that makes sense in retrospect" moments.

Answer (score 11):

As [A.bakker explained](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/113393), Marsellus is known to be jealous. But the main issue is that Vincent thinks it will be a straightforward assignment, and he would have no problem avoiding anything that would make Marsellus jealous.

But he hasn't *met* Mia, who is, well, not exactly boring, is she?

His plan to "sit across a table, chew [his] food with [his] mouth closed, laugh at her jokes, and that's all [he's] gonna do" is not as easy as he thinks.

Answer (score 5):

He's laughing because Mia is Marsellus' wife, and he is known to be jealous.

In a previous conversation between Vincent and Jules (While driving to get the briefcase) they discussed his jealousy, allegedly throwing a man off a balcony for giving his wife a foot massage. Vincent dismisses it as an urban legend/exaggeration stating that he isn't nervous and nothing special will happen. While Jules implies that him taking out Mia might be a suicide mission due to the jealous nature of Marsellus.